# Angular Testing With Mocha & Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've setup an angularjs project using yeoman (generator-angular 0.7.1).

My tests are running fine as well, using karma & jasmine.

Now I wanted to add some tests that use jasmine's `argsFor` & `clock` functions. When I did it, I realized that I'm using Jasmine 1.3 that doesn't support it. I changed my package.json: instead of `"karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5"` I now have `"karma-jasmine": "~0.2.2"`, but now all the tests (that passed by now), are failing for:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'running' of undefined
at isSpecRunning (C:/some_path/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1924:65)
```

I didn't change these tests. This isn't even related to the `argsFor`/`clock` functions.

How can I change my configuration to work with jasmine 2.0 smoothly? Couldn't make it work...

Comment: could be this [closed issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/25)

try updating angular